# Проход по двум коллекциям в Java 8 stream api

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Встал вопрос, как переписать проход по двум разным коллекциям с присвоением данных под Java 8 Stream api.

```
for (User user : userList){
    for (Car car : carList){
        if (car.getCarOwner().getId() == user.getId()){
            car.setCarOwner(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно в лоб)

```
userList.forEach(user -> {
    carList.stream()
        .filter(car -> car.getCarOwner().getId() == user.getId())
        .forEach(car -> car.setCarOwner(user));
});
```