# Stream api and collection

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Есть 2 коллекции collection 1 и collection 2.Есть 2 цикла foreach:

```
    for(col1:collection1)
           for(col2:collection2)
             if(col2.someMethod2()==0)
               col1.someMethod1();
```

Проблема в том,как используя stream api в java,реализовать код выше.Я дохожу до:

```
col1.forEach(c->c.stream().filter(f->f.someMethod2()==0)...
```

Как проходя по collection2 с помощью foreach вызывать данные извне(т.е. из collection1)?Получается что внутренний foreach работает только с элементами из второй коллекции.

Comment: Не оно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768790/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b2-java-8-stream-api?rq=1

Comment: @AntonShchyrov чистый дубликат

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проход по двум коллекциям в Java 8 stream api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768790/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b2-java-8-stream-api)

Comment: я отвечал на такой вопрос совсем недавно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081396/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-stream-api/1081421#1081421

Comment: Вот примеры выше похожи,но суть немного другая.Выше проход идет по списку col2,далее накладывается фильтр и работа ведется опять таки с объектами из col2.Мне нужно чтобы после filter(),я мог вывать какой-нибудь метод из col1.Если с примером выше про car and user:то после if мне нужно вызвать user.getId();

Comment: @Дмитрий это было бы то,если я например вызвал бы какой нибудь метод group после filter